# How can I use 'echo' output as an operand for the 'seq' command within a terminal?

Tags: bash, shell

I have an excercise where I need to sum together every digit up until a given number like this:

Suppose I have the number 12, I need to do 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+1+0+1+1+1+2.

(numbers past 9 are split up into their separate digits eg. 11 = 1+1, 234 = 2+3+4, etc.)

I know I can just use:

```
seq -s '' 12
```

which outputs 123456789101112 and then add them all together with '+' in between and then pipe to 'bc' BUT I have to specifically do :

```
echo 12 | ...
```

as the first step (because the online IDE fills it in as the unchangeable first step for every testcase) and when I do this I start to have problems with seq

I tried

```
echo 12 | seq -s '' $1

### or just ###

echo 12 | seq -s ''
```

but can't get it to work as this just gives back a *missing operand* error for seq (because I'm in the terminal, not a script and the '12' isn't just assigned to $1 I assume), any recommendations on how to avoid it or how to get seq to interpret the 12 from echo as operand or alternative ways to go?

Comment: You could capture your `echo` output in a variable and then use the variable in your `seq` command: `target=$(echo "12"); seq -s '' $target`

Comment: that would work, but it's absolutely required for this that 'echo 12 | ' is the first part of the command sequence (I know it sounds dumb)

Comment: You need a command that will read 12 (or whatever) from standard input. For pure shell, that would be the `read` command.

Comment: Frankly, though, this is a terrible exercise for shell, because you simply won't be writing code that needs to split a number into its component digits often, if at all.

Comment: `echo 12 | { read num; seq -s '' "$num" ... }`

Comment: you've stated *`it's absolutely required for this that 'echo 12 | ' is the first part of the command`* ... who/what is requiring this? is this some sort of homework assignment and if it is, what's been covered recently in class?  please update the question with your code that introduces the plus signs and feeds to `bc`

Comment: @markp-fuso it's homework that goes through an online interpreter/excercise platform called Dodona which has automatically filled in 'echo 12 | ' or whatever number it uses in the testcases for this excercise up front, I can use any other command or any amount of lines, just can't change that first step. I feel like adding in the rest wouldn't really be on topic for my specific question

Comment: `echo 12 | seq -s '' $(< /dev/stdin)`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano exactly what I was looking for, hadn't thought of that, thank you!

Comment: Note that `seq -s '' "$(cat)"` works with all POSIX-compatible shells.  `$(< file)` is a [bashism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bashism).  ([Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) correctly issues a warning if you don't put double quotes around `$(cat)` or `$(< /dev/stdin)`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or

```
echo 12 | { echo $(( $({ seq -s '' $(< /dev/stdin); echo; } | sed -E 's/([[:digit:]])/\1+/g; s/$/0/') )); }
```

without `sed`:

```
d=$(echo 12 | { seq -s '' $(< /dev/stdin); echo; }); echo $(( "${d//?/&+}0" ))
```

Comment: See [What's wrong with var=$(</dev/stdin) to read stdin into a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716438/264812).

Comment: @pjh right, but this case is not among the ones that could be wrong

Answer (score 2):

`seq -s '' $(cat)`

full solution:

```
echo "12" | seq -s '' $(cat) | sed 's/./&+/g; s/$/0/' | bc
```

Comment: See [What's wrong with var=$(</dev/stdin) to read stdin into a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716438/264812).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 12 | awk '{
cnt=0
for(i=1;i<=$1;i++) {
    cnt+=i
    printf("%s%s",i,i<$1?"+":"=")
    }
    print cnt
}'
```

Prints:

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12=78
```

---

If it is supposed to be just the digits added up:

```
echo 12 | awk '{s=""
                for(i=1;i<=$1;i++) s=s i 
                split(s,ch,"")
                for(i=1;i<=length(ch); i++) cnt+=ch[i]
                print cnt
}'
51
```

Or a POSIX pipeline:

```
$ echo 12 | seq -s '' "$(cat)" | sed -E 's/([0-9])/\1+/g; s/$/0/' | bc
51
```

Comment: I need to add together every single digit, not the sequence of numbers until the given number. 
So everything past 9 need to be split up in it's own seperate digits (11= 1+1, 234 = 2+3+4, etc.)